# Struggling to get the range of $1/(x/(x+1))$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

When I try to graph this to find the range, all I get is $y$ can't be equal to zero, while the solution is $y$ can't be equal to one or zero.
To graph it, I need to use the alternate form $1+(1/x)$ which results in the wrong range.

Comment: Is the function $\frac{1}{x/x+1}$? Or, equivalently, $\frac{x+1}{x}$?

Comment: Its your first one ,exactly how I wrote it ,its a composite function changing it to an alternate form will result in wrong results

Answer (score 3):

The expression $\frac1{\frac x{1+x}}$ is not defined when $x=0$ or $x=-1$. On the other hand, for all other $x$, we have the equality $\frac1{\frac x{1+x}}=\frac{1+x}x=1+\frac 1x$. Hence the range of $\frac1{\frac x{1+x}}$ with $x$ varying over all allowed values is the same as the range of $1+\frac 1x$ when $x$ varies over all values except $0$ and $-1$. If we are talking about real numbers here, this makes the range $\Bbb R\setminus \{0,1\}$.

Comment: Well both wolframalpha and my professor agree that the range is R\{0,1}